# XC8 compiler: Same variable names across different C source files causes issues

Tags: microchip, mplabx, compiler, xc8

I am currently working with a PIC18F25k80 device using the XC8 compiler and MPLABX.

I spent the whole of yesterday trying to debug some code I ported from a PIC32 micro project. This code did not interact with any hardware, and was split into 2 different source files.

Eventually, I was able to solve the issue by identifying that the XC8 compiler produces unexpected results when variables of the same name exist in different source files. NOTE: I did not use the "extern" keyword, as I needed the variables to be logically different across the source files.

I had to prefix all my my variables with a source file specific prefix.

Is this a known issue with the XC8 compilers?

Comment: You are not allowed to use same name for global variables, unless these are `static`. This is standard C, not specific to XC8

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for this. I just read up on the "static" keyword and it makes sense now. If i do use the "static" keyword to limit the scope to a single source file, i am assuming references in the source wont conflict right ?

Comment: Even with `static`you should'nt use the same name for different variables for readability.

Comment: @Mike In my scenario, i have different source files that i manage as "classes / objects". A variable name like "count" used in each context should not affect readability. or ?

Answer (score 2):

That is perfectly normal under any compiler.

By default, if you declare variable X in modules A and B then these will be the same variable, as by default these will have `extern` linkage, unless otherwise told with `static` linkage.

You would see that if you declare the variables with initial value, i.e. `int X = 3;` in module `A` and `int X = 4;` in module `B`, then the compiler will complain that you can't initialize the same variable twice.